# Drop duplicates only if boolean/specifics are met

Tags: pandas

I'd like to drop rows only if certain values are true. Specifically in my case, I'd like to drop only duplicate rows where Holiday = True and the name and date match. This hopefully gives you an idea of what I'm going for (obviously doesn't work).

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['name', 'date', 'holiday' == True], keep='first')
```

```
   name        date holiday       subject
0  mary  11-26-2020    True           PTO
1  mary  11-26-2020    True  Thanksgiving
2  jake  11-01-2020   False       Meeting
3  jake  11-01-2020   False       Meeting
4  andy  11-08-2020   False       Project
```

```
0  mary  11-26-2020    True  Thanksgiving
1  jake  11-01-2020   False       Meeting
2  jake  11-01-2020   False       Meeting
3  andy  11-08-2020   False       Project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df['holiday']
df = pd.concat([
    df.loc[mask].drop_duplicates(subset = ['name', 'date'], keep='first'),
    df.loc[~mask],
])
```

(1) you split the whole data frame by the column `holiday`

(2) deduplicate one part, leave the other untouched

(3) concatenate both parts

Comment: I have a question here: how come your method only drops duplicated if holiday is True? There is no mention of it. I don't understand how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Because it applies `.drop_duplicates(...)` only on a part where `holiday==True` (this is achieved by first `.loc[...]` which filters only the records where `holiday==True`), second `.loc[...]` adds the piece with `holiday==False`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
mask = df.duplicated(['name', 'date'], keep='last') & df['holiday']
print(df[~mask])
```

**Output**

```
   name        date  holiday       subject
1  mary  11-26-2020     True  Thanksgiving
2  jake  11-01-2020    False       Meeting
3  jake  11-01-2020    False       Meeting
4  andy  11-08-2020    False       Project
```